# Do Monitors have apis to change input source

Tags: monitor

I have two monitors BENq rl2450h and Soniq

I want to be able to change the source of the input for these two monitors..

Would a piece of software be able to change this. Are there open source alternatives to do this.. I'm happy to code if there is no alternative.

### Use Case

2 different cables connected to 1 Monitor eg. 1 could be hdmi the other a VGA source.

I want to be able to let the software decide which input source to be used on a particular monitor...

### Limitations

I cannot use a switch from D-link (or other companies) because its not a publicly accessible PC ... It needs to be done using a software approach .. Additionally, [Change Monitor Input Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553867/change-monitor-input-source)  suggests a C# method but I would prefer  something that is cross platform so can be coded for multiple OS's .. say python for eg.

Comment: did you search the internet before asking that question here? because it kind of feels like maybe you didn't...

Comment: @Mike This question now actually comes up as the first result to many relevant Google searches.

Comment: Yeah, the downside of someone writing a question and then walking away from it. This could have been googled at the time of asking, but now shows up as first result in google, having zero value.